# Sql order string with numbers asc

Tags: mysql, sql

I have strings in my db like this:

```
DE-1016-860
DE-1016-1078
DE-1016-1166
```

How can I `ORDER BY order_numbers` this elements in a `SELECT` like this:

```
DE-1016-1166
DE-1016-1078
DE-1016-860
```

Comment: is the string format fixed?

Comment: @vkp Yes of course and the type is varchar(255)

Comment: @ItsOdi, did my answer below help?

Comment: @RobertoNavarro I'm just home now I'll test it now and give you a answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This assumes your prefix is always the same, thus to_number the last characters:

```
  SELECT str
    FROM (SELECT 'DE-1016-860' str FROM DUAL
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 'DE-1016-1078' str FROM DUAL
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 'DE-1016-1166' str FROM DUAL)
ORDER BY TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (str, 9, 4)) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks man for this fast answer :) I'll try it when I'm back home!

Comment: I don't know the order number and only the first 8 characters are the same

Comment: I tried this: ORDER BY SUBSTRING(order_number, 8) ASC 
but the table always show
DE-1016-1078
DE-1016-1166 //This sould be at the top
DE-1016-860

Answer (score 0):

If your format is always `AA-####-.........`
then you can try using `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()`, and `SUBSTRING()`.

For example:

```
ORDER BY LEFT(order_number,2), SUBSTRING(order_number,4,4) DESC, SUBSTRING(order_number, 9,4) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
ORDER BY SUBSTR(order_number FROM 1 FOR 8), CAST(SUBSTR(order_number FROM 8) AS UNSIGNED)
```

First I gave them the value 1 for the startpoint and 8 for the endpoint:

```
12345678
DE-1016-
```

You can see the eight characters. Second I make a cast from the eighth number and it works fine. It give me my numbers sorted by by the highest at the top to the smallest at the end.